# Request for api not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm making a request but it doesn't seem to work. If I copy code into my browser it works good, but in my console it shows up this :

```
{
  "status" : "success",
  "data" : {
    "error_message" : "API access enabled, but unable to verify two-factor authentication code. If you need help with this, please contact support@bitskins.com."
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? It's based on two-factor authentication that as I said works good while printing the url itself and when i'm copying it into my browser.

```
var url = 'https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price/?api_key='+bitskins.apikey+'&code='+bitskins.code+'&names='+encodeURIComponent(items[i].market_hash_name)+'&delimiter=!END!';
                console.log(url);
                request(url, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error) {
                        console.log(body)
                    }
                });
```

In case you want, here is my api key module to generating it (api key deleted for security)

```
var TOTP = require('onceler').TOTP;

//Create a TOTP object with your secret
var totp = new TOTP('deleted');

// print out a code that's valid right now
// console.log(totp.now());

var code = totp.now();

module.exports = {
    code: code,
    apikey: 'deleted'
}
```

Comment: Give us a link to the documentation of the API

Comment: @aryehArmon [api documentation link](https://bitskins.com/api)

Comment: where are you declaring the bitskins.apikey var?

Comment: @AryehArmon In the bitskins file (that's included in my post, last block, just deleted my api key from it)

Didn't know, I guess it wouldn't be a big deal anyway

Comment: what does totp.now(); print?

Comment: It prints the two factor authenticator code from apikey. And it is working.

Comment: Could you give example for the `names` field?

Comment: @isabek Here is example of the whole generated link
[example, link was bugging](https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price/?api_key=456e206e-a444-45d4-8fe4-7be8a2853638&code=730813&names=Tec-9%20%7C%20Sandstorm%20(Minimal%20Wear)&delimiter=!END!)
Now of course this won't show data because code expired, but it was working properly when copy pasted into browser immediately, just wouldn't show up on request.

Comment: Your links work because you have authorized. If you will try it not authorized session it will not work. I have found one solution but it is not solid. There should be another way to implement.

Comment: @isabek isn't it authorized with this apikey and code generated? May I know which solution you've found? Maybe it will help me finding a way to deal with it somehow

Comment: Also I think TOTP generates maybe wrong codes. I have entered code from google authenticator and it works normally.

Comment: @isabek It generates the right codes, as I said while i'm copy pasting this url into my browser it works, but it doesn't in the request function.

Comment: Do you have secret and api keys?

Answer (score 0):

Founder of BitSkins, Inc. here. You need to have the following:

1) Your API Key 
2) Your Secure Access Secret

You see the Secret when you enable Secure Access. If you do not have this, just disable/re-enable Secure Access and note the Secret down. The TOTP code you generate is with that Secret. Generate the TOTP code right before every API call and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot of your answer.

My api key and TOTP code seems to be fine, while im printing it inside a loop and copy pasting into my browser it all looks okay (if I do this fast enough while the code is still viable). The only problem I have is that the request function doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work. For me it works fine.

```
var API_KEY = ''; //It is very important
var SECRET_KEY = ''; //It is very important

var totp = new TOTP(SECRET_KEY);
var code = totp.now();

var options = {
  url: 'https://bitskins.com/api/v1/get_item_price',
  form: {
    'api_key': API_KEY,
    'names': 'Tec-9%20%7C%20Sandstorm%20(Minimal%20Wear)',
    'delimiter': '!END!',
    'code': code
  }
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error) {
    var info = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(info);
  }
}

request.post(options, callback);
```

Comment: I got it working, actually I was using api key instead of the secret one... Newbie mistakes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What npm package do you use to create 2FA code? I'm using "onceler" from example but I think it creates wrond codes. Here is my code:

```
var API_KEY = ''; //correct key from settings page
var SECRET_KEY = ''; // correct key which I copied from form with QR code.
var totp = new TOTP("SECRET_KEY");
var code = totp.now();
```

This code doesn't equal code which I can see in my mobile device and with this code I get error message like in author's question. But if I put code from my mobile in programm code - it works fine. So what package should I use to get correct codes?

Comment: And obviosly I use SECRET_KEY without " "

Comment: It is giving me correct codes although I have to use it right before I use it. Make sure you're using correct secret keys, it's working for sure.